# How to give a custom name to the PDF being downloaded using FPDF library?

Tags: php, html, pdf, fpdf

*The help I expect is written at the end as **Question**. Please refer that so that you might be able to skip the whole explanation and save time if you already know the solution.*

I am using FPDF library. By default, the library lets me open the PDF in the browser itself.

I want the file to be downloaded instead of opening in the browser, so I made a button and gave it a **download** attribute as the following.

```
<a download href="pdf_conversion/actionpdf.php?mypdf=<?php echo $mypdf ?>"><button>Download PDF</button></a>
```

Now, the download works fine, and the file that is being saved gets the name **doc.pdf**, which if I understand correctly, is the default name given to it by the library in the following **Output** function.

```
function Output($name='', $dest='')
{
// Output PDF to some destination
if($this->state<3)
    $this->Close();
$dest = strtoupper($dest);
if($dest=='')
{
    if($name=='')
    {
        $name = 'doc.pdf';
        $dest = 'I';
    }
    else
        $dest = 'F';
}
switch($dest)
{
    case 'I':
        // Send to standard output
        $this->_checkoutput();
        if(PHP_SAPI!='cli')
        {
            // We send to a browser
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$name.'"');
            header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
        }
        echo $this->buffer;
        break;
    case 'D':
        // Download file
        $this->_checkoutput();
        header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
        header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        echo $this->buffer;
        break;
    case 'F':
        // Save to local file
        $f = fopen($name,'wb');
        if(!$f)
            $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
        fwrite($f,$this->buffer,strlen($this->buffer));
        fclose($f);
        break;
    case 'S':
        // Return as a string
        return $this->buffer;
    default:
        $this->Error('Incorrect output destination: '.$dest);
}
return '';
}
```

The function **Output** is being called at the end of **actionpdf.php** as

```
$pdf->Output();
```

Now, I need the file name to be the value of **mypdf** which is being fetched from the URL using the GET method. I believe that I should be passing **$mypdf** as an argument in the **Output** function in the **actionpdf.php** page. I'm forced to believe that my entire logic is terribly wrong or the way I pass the variable is terribly wrong, because passing the variable as **$pdf->Output($mypdf);** result in a save-file pop up window which has **actionpdf.htm** as the file.

**Question : How do I take the value of a variable from the URL using GET method, and make that value as the name of the PDF file that is being downloaded. I am making use of the FPDF library.**

Comment: You are right: `$pdf->Output($mypdf);`

Comment: I thought so too. When the function **Output** has no arguments given, the correct PDF file gets downloaded (doc.pdf). But when I give the argument like that, the file that get downloaded is actionpdf.htm (actionpdf.php after it is saved on my disk). It's not *.pdf*. Could you please check the **Output** function in the library code and help me out with the problem?
@colburton

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to grab a parameter in your URL path using GET do the following :

```
$myparameter = $_GET["myparameter"];
```

As here $myparameter will contain the value passed in URL as : `http://url/myfile.php?myparameter=myvalue`

Now all you have to do is pass that to the Output method:

```
$pdf->Output($myparameter);
```

Just for the record, you'd better test if the parameter you're looking for exists, let's say your default PDF file should be "pdf.pdf" :

```
$mypdf = "pdf";

if(isset($_GET["filename"]) && is_string($_GET["filename"])) {
    $mypdf = $_GET["filename"];
}

//add the following line, NOTICE THE DOT BEFORE THE EQUAL (.=)
$mypdf .= ".pdf";

$pdf->Output($mypdf);
```

Comment: I did the same thing. But when the function **Output** has no arguments given, the correct PDF file gets downloaded (doc.pdf). But when I give the argument like that, the file that get downloaded is actionpdf.htm (actionpdf.php after it is saved on my disk). It's not *.pdf*. Could you please check the **Output** function in the library code and help me out with the problem?

Comment: I added a line to the code I provided in my response, try that and tell me if it works :) NEVER MODIFY THE SOURCE CODE OF A LIBRARY.

Answer (score -1):

I figured out what the problem was. All I had to do was, pass the argument just like I was doing, and then make a small change in the **Output** function as the following.

```
if($dest=='')
{
if($name=='')
{
    $name = 'doc.pdf';
    $dest = 'I';
}
else
    $dest = 'I';
 }
```

The original code had **$dest = 'F'** in the *else* condition, which caused the issue.

Comment: So why don't you simply pass "I" as the [$dest parameter](http://fpdf.org/en/doc/output.htm) when you think that this "was" the problem?

Comment: That could work too, I guess... I was trying to figure out the Output function in the library, and that worked. As far as I could see, that wouldn't cause me any problem. And hence, I left it at that. Am I wrong?